# Updating list values with new values read - Python

Tags: python, input

I was't really sure how to ask this. I have a list of 3 values initially set to zero. Then I read 3 values in at a time from the user and I want to update the 3 values in the list with the new ones I read.

```
cordlist = [0]*3
```

Input:
3 4 5

I want list to now look like:
[3, 4, 5]

Input: 
2 3 -6

List should now be
[5, 7, -1]

How do I go about accomplishing this? This is what I have:

```
cordlist += ([int(g) for g in raw_input().split()] for i in xrange(n))
```

but that just adds a new list, and doesn't really update the values in the previous list

Comment: @JosefAssad That's not a duplicate

Comment: It is. The approved answer in that post is a correct solution to this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do something like this:

```
cordlist = [0, 0, 0]
for i in xrange(n):
    cordlist = map(sum, zip(cordlist, map(int, raw_input().split())))
```

Breakdown:

- `map(int, raw_input().split())` is equivalent to `[int(i) for i in raw_input().split()]`
- `zip` basically takes a number a lists, and returns a list of tuples containing the elements that are in the same index. See the [docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) for more information.
- `map`, as I explained earlier, applies a function to each of the elements in an iterable, and returns a list. See the [docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map) for more information.

Comment: That reduces the list to a single number.

Comment: @msvalkon does it? It works fine with me.

Comment: yeah I'm on python 2.7. If I type in 3, 2 and 1 `cordlist` becomes `[6]`.

Comment: Yup,that seems to work. Thanks very much, however if you don't mind can you explain why it works?

Comment: @msvalkon you must have copied the code incorrectly.

Comment: @Volatility well there we go, my ipython had a previous variable `n` with a value of 3. Sorry for this, I'm an idiot.

Comment: @Smac89 see the edit. Hopefully I've explained it clearly enough.

Answer (score 2):

```
In [17]: import numpy as np

In [18]: lst=np.array([0]*3)

In [19]: lst+=np.array([int(g) for g in raw_input().split()])

3 4 5

In [20]: lst
Out[20]: array([3, 4, 5])

In [21]: lst+=np.array([int(g) for g in raw_input().split()])

2 3 -6

In [22]: lst
Out[22]: array([ 5,  7, -1])
```

Comment: see my numpy solution!

Answer (score 1):

```
cordlist = [v1+int(v2) for v1, v2 in zip(cordlist, raw_input().split())]
```

tested like that:

```
l1 = [1,2,3]
l2 = [2,3,4]
print [v1+v2 for v1, v2 in zip(l1, l2)]
```

result: [3, 5, 7]

Answer (score 0):

I would go that way using [`itertools.zip_longest`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest):

```
from itertools import zip_longest

def add_lists(l1, l2):
    return [int(i)+int(j) for i, j in zip_longest(l1, l2, fillvalue=0)]

result = []
while True:  
    l = input().split()
    print('result = ', add_lists(result, l))
```

Output:

```
>>> 1 2 3
result =  [1, 2, 3]
>>> 3 4 5
result =  [4, 6, 8]
```

Answer (score 0):

More compact version of @namit's numpy solution

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> lst = np.zeros(3, dtype=int)
>>> for i in range(2):
        lst += np.fromstring(raw_input(), dtype=int, sep=' ')


3 4 5
2 3 -6
>>> lst
array([ 5,  7, -1])
```